# Rails object inheritance with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I have a simple has_many/belongs_to relationship between Report and Chart. The issue I'm having is that my Chart model is a parent that has children.

So in my Report model I have

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charts
end
```

And my Chart model is a parent, where Pie, Line, Bar all inherit from Chart. I'm not sure where the belongs_to :report belongs within the chart model, or children of chart model. I get errors when I attempt to access chart.report because the object is of type "Class"

> undefined local variable or method `report' for #< Class:0x104974b90>

The Chart model uses STI so its pulling say.. 'Gender' from the chart_type column in the charts table.. what am I missing?

**EDIT**

```
      Chart
      /  \
    Pie  Line
    / \
   /   \
Gender Sex
```

I am (using STI) instantiating an object of type Gender, or Sex. Hopefully this helps a bit more.

I have a feeling that its caused by

```
@chart.update_attributes(params[:chart])
```

because when submitted its actually params[:chart] its params[:gender] or params[:sex]

Comment: 1. Does your Chart table have a 'type' column?
2. Do your Pie and Line classes inherit from Chart? (`Pie < Chart`)
3. What are you trying to illustrate about Gender and Sex in your tree? Are they also classes? Or attributes of the Pie model?

Comment: 1. Yes, chart_type, which I handle with a getter in the model. 2. Yes, Pie inherits from Chart. 3. Gender and Sex are model, since they have their own calculations they would run on the data. Each model, or chart type, has a method to calculate values, then calls super to display since they all display the same type of chart (Pie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have one controller receiving all these different types of models.  When you use the Rails form helpers, they're taking the object type from the instance and using that to populate the params.  This means that you have `params[:gender]` instead of `params[:chart]`

You can fix this by overriding the method that Rails uses to generate the form.  Put the following code in your base chart class:

```
def self.model_name
  name = "chart"
  name.instance_eval do
    def plural;   pluralize;   end
    def singular; singularize; end
  end
  return name
end
```

Now, any class that is a child of Chart will be passed into your receiving action as `params[:chart]`

Keep in mind that changing the object name as I've outlined above **could** break functionality of some plugins/gems that rely on it.  You should look into having multiple controllers.  Instead of having a `ChartsController` to receive all of the data, have a `GenderChartsController` and a `LineChartsController`.  This provides two benefits:

1. You don't need to change the object name
2. If you need custom code for a specific type of chart in the future, you don't have to add conditional statements to make it work, as the different controllers have segregated it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use just

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charts
end

class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
end
```

and call

```
@chart.report
@pie.report
@line.report
@bar.report
```

Comment: Thing is the @chart object in your example would actually be an instantiation of a Pie chart which is a child of Chart.

Comment: I used `@chart` as an instance of `Chart`.

Comment: right, which works fine for me. Its when I try to use Gender, or Sex that it becomes an issue. Using STI for some reason the object appears to be of type "Class"

Comment: How does your models look like?

Comment: Models diagram is in the question

Comment: Are Gender and Sex instances of Pie? Or do they inherit and add new functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If all the chart types belong to a report, then place

```
 belongs_to :report
```

in the parent model ( that is Chart Model in your case I am guessing).

Comment: I get the same error, do I need something else in the Report model? Something other has_many :charts ?

Comment: are you calling Chart.report ( that would give Class error, thats wrong ), you can only call this method on that chart model objects

Comment: something like "chart = Chart.find(:first)" and "chart.report"

Answer (score 0):

Your `chart_type` column needs to be renamed to just `type`, unless you explicitly overwrote `Base.inheritance_column`.

Did you explicitly rename the single table inheritance column to `chart_type`?

Comment: i have the following in my chart model  "set_inheritance_column :chart_type"